# Why the container in "macvlan" network cannot connect to the Internet?

Tags: docker

I just configured `macvlan` network for testing purposes and after I connected the container to that network I just cannot ping to DNS server of Google (8.8.8.8) from the container, I guess the container doesn't have the connection to the Internet.
What I am doing wrong here? Should my container be able to ping?

Commands executed:

```
docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=192.168.1.0/24 --gateway=192.168.1.1 -o parent=wlp2s0 macvlan50
docker run -it --network macvlan50 --ip 192.168.1.88 alpine /bin/sh
/ # ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
```

Output of ifconfig of the host: (I keep the output simple):

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
wlp2s0: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.11  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

Docker version: 20.10.14

Comment: Looks like you’re using Wi-Fi. Wi-Fi cannot be bridged (which is what _macvlan_ does internally). Maybe check out _ipvlan_.

Comment: @DanielB The same thing I tried in Virtual Machine of AWS(EC2) where the network interface was "eth0" and the container again didn't have the connection to the Internet.